# JavaScript Object Sorting By Date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, object

I am trying to sort my array of objects which have date values by date newest first and newest last.

I have the following code:

```
function comp(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.jsDate) - new Date(b.jsDate);
}

function compNewestFirst(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.jsDate) - new Date(a.jsDate);
}
```

Please note JS Date is a valid date/format the new Date() accepts.

I can getting it ordering oldest first but not newest first and I have tried the following:

```
return new Date(b.jsDate) + new Date(a.jsDate);
```

Current I CANNOT sort by newest date first and it only works OLDEST first.

Thanks

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How do I sort newest first rather than oldest first

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
function compNewestFirst(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.jsDate).getTime() - new Date(a.jsDate).getTime();
}
```

The return will be a negative integer and you will be able to order.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/huuorxso/2/);

Comment: why use `getTime()` ?

Comment: @Hacketo You are right. Don't need to use `getTime()` because the subtraction will already return the result in milliseconds